# Isosceles triangle $ABC$ with an inside point $M$, find $\angle BMC$

Tags: geometry

We have an isosceles $\triangle ABC, AC=BC, \measuredangle ACB=40^\circ$ and a point $M$ such that $\measuredangle MAB=30^\circ$, $\measuredangle MBA=50^\circ$.
Find $\measuredangle BMC$.
[image]
Starting with $\angle ABC=\angle BAC=70^\circ \Rightarrow \angle CBM=20 ^\circ$. Let us construct the equilateral $\triangle ABH$. If we look at $\triangle ACH, \angle ACH=20^\circ$ and $\angle CAH=10^\circ$. Can we show $\triangle AHC \cong CHB$? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Construct the equilateral triangle $AHB$. Given that $AC = BC, AH = BH$ and the shared $CH$, the triangles $AHC$ and $BHC$ are congruent. Then, $\angle BCH = \dfrac12\angle ACB = 20^\circ$.

Since $AH = BH$ and $\angle BAM = \angle HAM = 30^\circ$, the triangles $BAM$ and $HAM$ are congruent, which yields $\angle HBM = \angle BHM = \angle HBC = 10^\circ$ and $HM || CB$.

Then, the triangles $CHB$ and $BHC$ have the same altitudes $h$ with respect to the base $BC$. Since $\angle BCH = \angle CBM = 20^\circ$, we have $CH = BM = h\cot 20^\circ$.

As a result, the triangles $CHB$ and $BMC$ are congruent, which leads to,

$$\angle BMC = \angle CHB = 180^\circ - \angle CBH - \angle BCH = 180^\circ - 10^\circ - 20^\circ = 150^\circ$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you think of a solution that does not use trigonometry? Can we say that since $AC=BC$ and $AH=BH$, $CH$ is the bisector of $AB$? And we know that $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles and $AB$ is the base. Therefore, $\angle BCH=\angle ACH=\dfrac{1}{2}\angle ACB=20^\circ$.

Comment: Also, I would like to ask how do we conclude $\angle HBM=\angle BHM=\angle HBC=10^\circ$ using the congruent triangles $BAM$ and $HAM$?

Comment: Hey, did you see my comments?

Comment: @Justdoit - to claim CH is a bisector, you need to show ∠BCH=∠ACH.

Comment: @Justdoit - congruent triangles BAM and HAM leads to ∠AHM=∠ABM=50, which leads to ∠HBM=∠BHM=∠HBC=10

Comment: The converse perpendicular bisector theorem states that if a point is equidistant from the endpoints of a line segment, then it is on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment. We have $AC=BC$ and $AH=BH$. That means the points $C$ and $H$ lie on the perpendicular bisector, or in other words, $CH$ is the perpendicular bisector.

Comment: As I said, I don't know trigonometric functions, and I am trying to come up with another way to show the congruence of $\triangle CHB \cong \triangle BMC$. Can we prove it without trigonometric functions? Also, I would like to ask, we conclude that $HM$ and $CB$ are parallel due to the fact that $\angle BHM=\angle CBH=10 ^\circ$ (alternate angles), right?

Comment: Can we show that $CH=BM$ in a different way?

Comment: @Justdoit - you may draw the altitudes HX and MY onto the base  BC. Since HX = MY and ∠HCX=∠MBY=20, the right triangles HCX and MBY are congruent, which leads to CH = BM.

Comment: Let me see this. Did you see the previous comments? Do you agree now that $CH$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$?

Comment: Hello? ..........

Comment: Is this method often used? (I mean constructing an equilateral triangle)

Comment: @Justdoit - Construction of equilateral triangle is a very effective method in geometric solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trigonometric approach. Let $\angle BCM=\varphi\Rightarrow \angle ACM=40^{\circ}-\varphi$. Apply the law of sines in $\triangle AMC$ and $\triangle BMC$:
$$\frac{AC}{CM}=\frac{\sin(80^{\circ}-\varphi)}{\sin(40^\circ)} \\ \frac{BC}{CM}=\frac{\sin(20^{\circ}+\varphi)}{\sin(20^\circ)} $$
Since $AC=BC$, the two ratios with the sines are equal. We have $\sin(40^\circ)=2\sin(20^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)$, so
$$\frac{\sin(80^{\circ}-\varphi)}{2\cos(20^\circ)}=\sin(20^\circ+\varphi) \Leftrightarrow \\ \sin(80^{\circ}-\varphi)=2\sin(20^\circ+\varphi)\cos(20^\circ)$$ Then use the sum-product identities:
$$\sin(80^{\circ}-\varphi)=\sin(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi+40^\circ) \Leftrightarrow \\
\sin(\varphi)=\sin(80^{\circ}-\varphi)-\sin(\varphi+40^\circ) \Leftrightarrow \\
\sin(\varphi)=2\sin(20^\circ-\varphi)\cos(60^\circ) \Leftrightarrow \\
\sin(\varphi)=\sin(20^\circ-\varphi) $$
Since $0<\varphi<40^{\circ}$, the last equality implies $\varphi=20^\circ-\varphi\Leftrightarrow \varphi=10^{\circ}$, and we find $\angle BMC=150^{\circ}$.